# How to create a pack for MSDT

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 have a Microsoft Support Diagnostic Tool (msdt.exe).

With this Microsoft support can get data from PCs and send back to their servers. This tool is also used by the troubleshooting tools of Windows to find problems and fix them if they exist.

¿How can i create my own troubleshooter that use MSDT?

I know it is possible because i saw sometime a MSDT who fix an in-house software. The fix had the extension DIAGCAB.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. This kinds of packages are called Troubleshooting Packs. And the technology are called [Windows Troubleshooting Platform (WTP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

They are written in Powershell, and you can do it using Troubleshooting Pack Designer who belongs to the Windows SDK.

Here is a simple example: [Creating a Custom Windows 7 Troubleshooting Pack](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/09/05/creating-a-custom-windows-7-troubleshooting-pack.aspx).